# Delete from two tables in one query without joining

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I have two tables

```
@Entity
data class Pet(val name, val creationTime)

@Entity
data class Item(val creationTime)
```

These two entities are unrelated.

I would like to make a query that deletes from both tables by `creationTime`. How can I do this?

```
@Dao
interface Organizer {
    @Query("") 
    fun deleteAllTables(val creationTime)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an option to all-in-one-query you can use two queries in one transaction ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction)).

I guess it would be logically the same as you want.

```
@Dao
interface Organizer {
    @Query("delete from pets where creationTime := creationTime") 
    fun deletePets(val creationTime)
    
    @Query("delete from items where creationTime := creationTime") 
    fun deleteItems(val creationTime)
    
    @Transaction
    fun deleteAllTables(val creationTime) { 
        deletePets(creationTime)
        deleteItems(creationTime)
    }
}
```